# Unable to see firebase phone authentication despite enabeling it from firebase console and adding the dependencies/

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have enabled phone verification in the Authentication Methods tab in firebase console. After Linking the app to console I see only Email Verification showing up on the Firebase assistant Tab in Android Studio. Am I missing a step? I have followed googles documentation for the same.

[image: console image]

[image: Android Studio Image]

Below are my Gradle files.

Project Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App Gradle

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sumeet.kalwardirectorytry1"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}











apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phone authentication is support at the 11.0.2 lib version change the lib version at your gradle also you need to update all the `Firebase` used libs to same version:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
```

Comment: New error   "Failed to resolve :'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'

Comment: Thanks, i have updated my Gradle builds and everything looks good. But still Android Studio assistant only shows Email Verification Option in It. Phone verification is enabled as well from Firebase console

Comment: it doesn't show it it shows only the email and password